# ofstream creating file but not writing to it in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, ofstream

I am writing an MFC program that has a dialog with an "Export" button that will take all of the data that has been entered into the file and export it to a .txt (at some point I want to change this to a .msg file...but that's a question for another day).

However, when I click the button, it creates the file but doesn't write anything inside the file. For testing, I removed everything except just a simple literal string and even that isn't printing. Here is the current code for that event: The myfile.flush() statement is leftover from when I had a loop that I was trying to print to the file.

```
void CEHDAHTTimerDlg::OnBnClickedExport()
{
    // in this function, we want to export the items to a text file
    std::ofstream myfile("TodayTime.txt");
    myfile.open("TodayTime.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << "The average call time is ";
        myfile.flush();
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_EXPORT, L"Export Unsuccessful! --     No File");
    }
}
```

Is there anything you all can think of that could be causing this? I've been at it for a few hours trying different things, like utilizing a myfile.write() function instead. I've searched a lot around here, reddit, and google in general trying to find out why this isn't writing.

I appreciate your help.

EDIT:

Okay, calling the myfile constructor the way that I did, by including the file name, went ahead and did what open file would have done

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `myfile.open()` creates the file for you(or maybe when you create the `ofstream` object). I assume `myfile.is_open()` is not the write conditional function. Research how to check if a file is open and try other ones. Maybe `!myfile.fail()` will work

Comment: *However, when I click the button, it creates the file but doesn't write anything inside the file*  -- Did you debug the program?  How do you know it entered the `if` block?

Comment: Why do you call both constructor which opens the file and `open`? Also, do you know to check the workind directory of your app?

Comment: Reading on how [std::ofstream works is required](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream). Sergey already picked off that the file is being opened twice. A flush immediately before a close is also not necessary. Close will flush. Close is also not necessary. destruction of the `ofstream` will occur on exit from the function and close the file. Further, there is no test to ensure the write was successful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

commenting out the redundant "open" solves it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    // in this function, we want to export the items to a text file
    std::ofstream myfile("TodayTime.txt");
//    myfile.open("TodayTime.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << "The average call time is ";
        myfile.flush();
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "didn't write" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I strongly suspect that you're invoking undefined behaviour by opening and already-open stream.

Comment: @SamuelOhrenberg :) it usually is then you know what to look for. The standard library is extremely minimalist and expects us to fulfil all preconditions. It doesn't perform redundant checks as a rule. You'll get used to it, and learn to like the performance and elegance that is achieved as a result.

Comment: @SamuelOhrenberg re your edit. it's not that you don't have to open the file. It's that you opened the file when you used the constructor that takes a filename. If you had used the default constructor, you would have had to subsequently open the file.

Comment: Oooooh, I get it. So the default constructor just creates an instance of "myfile", but it has an option to include the location of the file and open it automatically

Comment: @SamuelOhrenberg the ofstream is (as it's name suggests) a stream. A layer over the actual file handle. The constructor that takes a filename implicitly calls open() as part of the constructor. The destructor will automatically flush the stream and close the underlying file, if it's open. cppreference.com is a good place to read about these things. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream

Comment: There is no `undefined behaviour` here: the call to `open()` will fail because the stream is already associated with the file, setting the failbit. The call to `is_open()` will succeed, as the file is open. Then the call to streaming operator `<<` will fail (because of the failbit) - but who is checking? :)

Comment: @VladFeinstein if you make this an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the explanation:

1. The call to `myfile.open("TodayTime.txt");` will fail because the stream is already associated with the file, setting the failbit.
2. The call to `is_open()` will succeed, as the file is open.
3. Then the call to streaming operator `<<` will fail (because of the failbit).

Comment: Thanks. Then, what is the solution?

Comment: @quanta don't open the file twice :)

Answer (score 0):

this is because `myfile << "The average call time is ";` not working 
to fix that

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("TodayTime.txt",std::ios:app) //app for appending you can use trunc for
  //truncating file 
  //for flushing content's of existing file use myfile.flush();
if (!data_pack.is_open())
{
    std::cerr << "unable to open the file for writing";
}

 myfile << "some stuff tho write you can replace the string with variable"
  <<std::endl; //for next line
  //at last close file
   myfile.close();
```